# Find Total Authors

Tags: code

Please suggest a code snippet to get the total number of authors on a blog who have at least one published article. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hi **@rsm:**

There are probably better ways, using the WordPress API, but since I know SQL so well this immediately came to mind:

```
function total_published_authors() {
  global $wpdb;
  $sql =<<<SQL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_published_authors FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT
    {$wpdb->users}.ID
FROM {$wpdb->users} 
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} ON {$wpdb->posts}.post_author={$wpdb->users}.ID
WHERE 
    {$wpdb->posts}.post_status='publish'
GROUP BY 
    {$wpdb->users}.ID
) x
SQL;
  return $wpdb->get_var($sql);
}
```

If I come up with a better way I'll post it too.

Comment: Not really on API (as far as I remember), there is [`wp_list_authors()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_authors), but it's large and complex function to generate HTML output from SQL without any intermediary stuff.

Comment: @Rarst - You know, we really ought to go thorough WPSE and find all the questions that are answered by custom SQL, and build a wrapper around `WP_Query()` that lets people do the queries they need by passing arguments instead of forcing *them* to drop into SQL *(hint, hint. :)*

Comment: That sounds like a great idea,  like a super custom wp_query.

Comment: @בניית אתרים - Notice the *(hint, hint)*; consider what I told you about via email...